# Devolver datos de consulta con PHP Y Json

Tags: php, javascript, html, json

Saludos mi problema es el siguiente, estoy tratando hacer una consulta con PHP y jquery, donde envio un dato vacio, solo para que me devulva una fila de la base de datos MYSQL pero al mostrar los datos en el HTML me da esto

```
[object Object][object Object]
```

Mi codigo Js es el siguiente

```
$.getJSON("view_msj.php", function(mensajesd){

        $("#mensajes").append("<div>" + mensajesd + "</div>");

});
```

Y el PHP el siguiente

```
<?php

try{


    //$nom_msj = $_POST['dt_empys'];

    $base = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=quickchat", "root", "");

    $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $base->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");


//    $resultado=$base->query("SELECT NOMBRE FROM sala WHERE NOMBRE='$nom_msj'");


    $resultado=$base->query("SELECT MENSAJES FROM sala");

    $rows = $resultado->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    echo (json_encode($rows));


}catch(Exception $e){

    echo "Ha habido un error" . $e->GetMessage();
}
```

?>

Comment: intenta `var decodedMsg = JSON.parse(mensajesd)`

Comment: Para revisar la información correctamente puedes usar `console.log(mensajesd);`. Mira: [Uso de Console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/?hl=es) e indicarnos que datos te muestra.

Comment: Use console.log(mensajesd); y esto es lo que me muestra

[{"MENSAJES":"HOla mundo"},{"MENSAJES":"HOla mundo 2"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$resultado->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);` returna un array. Tienes que recorrer cada elemento del array y mostrarlos uno por uno con un `for`:

```
$.getJSON("view_msj.php", function(mensajesd){
   for(var i= 0; i < mensajesd.length;i++)
   {
     $("#mensajes").append("<div>" + mensajesd[i].MENSAJES + "</div>");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Listo, ya pude solventarlo con esto

```
$.getJSON("view_msj.php", function(mensajesd){
   for(var i= 0; i < mensajesd.length;i++)
   {
     $("#mensajes").append("<div>" + mensajesd[i].MENSAJES + "</div>");
   }
});
```